# LIQUIBASE restore from MSSQL backup failed

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

Using Liquibase I would like to apply multiple change sets, but first one is a restore-database script as follow:

```
<changeSet id="0" author="me" context="test or dev">
    <sql >
       RESTORE DATABASE CleanDB
       FROM DISK = '\\SomePublic\DevDB.bak'
       WITH REPLACE;
     </sql>
</changeSet>
<!-- here many changes go -->
```

Note `CleanDB` is new empty existing database. My connection url specifies `DevDB` as a target and looks: `url=jdbc:sqlserver://SomePublic;databaseName=CleanDB`

During execution I've gotten error:

> **liquibase**: RESTORE cannot process database 'CleanDB' because it is in use by this session. It is recommended that the master database be used when performing this operation.

So my question: how to apply Liquibase script to clear database that should be restored from some backup?

Comment: You can't restore the database to which you are connected. You need to change the JDBC URL to **not** include the database name

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name great, then how to apply rest of changes to my `CleanDB`?

Comment: You might try adding "USE master; GO;" as the first line. Just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SteveDonie comment I found the solution that is basing on 4 steps:

1. Switch to some other database (master for example)
2. Release usage of `CleanDB`;
3. apply backup to `CleanDB`
4. Restore usage and switch back from master to `CleanDB`.

So next code works for me:

```
<sql splitStatements="true">
    use master; <!-- switch to master -->
    <!-- avoid error that CleanDB already in use -->
    alter database ${databaseName}
    set single_user with rollback immediate;
    <!-- apply backup -->
    RESTORE DATABASE CleanDB
    FROM DISK = '\\SomePublic\DevDB.bak'
    WITH REPLACE;
    <!-- Restore access to database -->
    alter database ${databaseName}
    set multi_user;
    <!-- switch back for further Liquibase operations -->
    use ${databaseName};

 </sql>
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. To solve it I need to do a `alter database`. But I get this error message: `Migration failed for change set ... Failed SQL: ALTER DATABASE ${databaseName} ...`. So my problem is: Where does the property `databaseName` came from? Do I have to specify it manually (`<property ... />`) or is it a "built in" property in liquibase?

Comment: @CptS you can specify it over command line of liquebase `-DdatabaseName=YourDBName`